# iOS Modal Segue drops source ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, segue, viewcontroller

When doing a modal segue, does the originating ViewController get discarded after the segue is performed? I am setting the destination controller's delegate to the source ViewController, but when the destination ViewController.viewDidLoad, the self.delegate is nil...

The following code will produce the log message "ListViewController.viewDidLoad: My delegate is nil :("

[Source] MapViewController:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mapToList"]){
        NSLog(@"MapViewController.prepareForSegue: Segue mapToList being called, setting LisViewController's delegate to myself");
        [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
        if(!self){
            NSLog(@"MapViewController.prepareForSegue: I am nil.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"MapViewController.prepareForSegue: I am NOT nil.");
        }
    }
}
```

[Destination] ListViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(!self.delegate){
        NSLog(@"ListViewController.viewDidLoad: My delegate is nil :(");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ListViewController.viewDidLoad: My delegate populated");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `MapViewController.prepareForSegue: Segue mapToList ...` appear in the console?

Comment: Yes, sorry, felt like that would have been obvious. After some testing, specifically changing to a push segue, it seems that the original ViewController does get dismissed/cleared somehow...

Comment: I just did a fresh app and it works fine. [See it on github](https://github.com/mikezehrer/ModalDelegation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems correct, the only thing I have done differently is test this in a skeleton framework I have that is a tableviewcontroller nested in a navigationcontroller. I just tested with the following code and it works fine for me:

RootViewController .h:

```
@interface RootTableViewController : UITableViewController <newTest>
```

Prepare for Segue (in rootViewController):

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToModalView"]){
       [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];  
 }
}
```

Top of Modal View Controller .h:

```
@protocol newTest <NSObject>
  -(void) hello;
@end
```

Property Declaration in Modal View:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <newTest> delegate;
```

ViewDidLoad in Modal View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate);
}
```

My NSLog of self.delegate properly prints out and my code appears to be more or less the same as yours. Is your property declared correctly?

Comment: So, I think my problem is that my segue is to a NavigationView controller, but the TableViewController associated with that second NavigationViewController does not pass the delegate through...

Comment: Check this out... This is exactly my problem. When going to secondView, and pressing the button, it does not have a delegate set (i think due to not being passed from the NavigationController) - https://github.com/wuntee/SegueTest

Comment: You are misusing modal views in your git project. Modal views are designed to be displayed interacted with and then dismissed with a return to the view that presented them. There is no reason for it to navigate to a Navigation Controller (and it shouldn't). If you want to do that kind of segue, you should not be using modal.

Comment: The application I am trying to build has basically two flows, one that is initiated at UIView containing a Map and another that starts at a ListView. Suggestion on how to have that initial state? It is currently set up where a segmented controller flips between the two views via modal segue...

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you are trying to accomplish. I think this would be better served with a more direct chat. Do you have another means for me to get in touch with you?

Comment: This is not a misuse of a modal view. Many people do the same thing...the new nav controller is to take advantage of the features it provides and not to have to embed something in your own view controller.  For example to provide a top bar with a done and cancel button.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but I came upon it when running into the same issue myself.  Couple of things here:

1. To the guy who didn't understand why someone would want to use a Nav controller with a modal display - its to get the benefit of the nav bar without having to embed a UINavigationBar into your own view controller like tw airball did.
2. To solve the problem without resorting to what tw airball did remember that the destination view controller for the segue in this case is the navigation controller...not the view controller embedded in the nav.

So the fix is in your prepareForSeque:

```
UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
MyRealDestViewController *myRealDestViewController = (MyRealDestViewController)navController.topViewController;
myRealDestViewController.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the segue is to a `NavigationController` then the `destinationViewController` loses the delegate.

I got around this problem by having the modal segue into the `destinationViewController`, and then adding `NavigationBar` and `Bar Buttons` to simulate the navigation controller (I assume you wrapped the `destinationViewController` in a `NavigationController` for the "done" and "cancel" buttons).

Set the delegate as normal in the `rootViewController`:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToModalView"]){
     [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];  
   }
}
```

Hope that helps